# Pycharm "writing cursor" goes away when changing i3wm workspaces

Tags: vim, pycharm, manjaro, i3

I am using Manjaro with i3wm and Pycharm is in vim mode.
When I am using Pycharm and I change to a workspace and then come back to Pycharm, I have to click on the text for the "writing cursor" to come back.

(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Help -> Edit custom properties` (select yes if it asks you to create a file) and then paste in `suppress.focus.stealing=false` and restart the editor.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to press `Ctrl+F` and then `Esc`.